# How to cast java.lang.reflect.Field to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement to use for Keyword Driven in Page Factory Framework

Tags: java, reflection, casting, webdriver, pageobjects

A snippet of the LoginPage -

```
Class LoginPage extends BaseClass {
public LoginPage() throws Exception {
    eDriver = BrowserDriver.getDriverInstance();
    PageFactory.initElements(eDriver, this);
}
@FindBy(name = "rememberMe")
public WebElement rememberMe_checkbox;

}
```

The current framework is using page factory and page object.  But, I also want to be keyword driven.

The keywords in the excel file is defined as follows -

```
    class       element_name            action
    LoginPage   rememberMe_checkbox     click
```

In the keyword action class, I am able to get the LoginPage class object.  I can get 'rememberMe_checkbox' WebElement field.  But I couldn't get it to cast to WebElement.

I'm getting this error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.reflect.Field to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement

Here is what I have so far -

```
public class ActionKeywords {
public void enter_Text(String className, String elementName, String textValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
ClassLoader classLoader = ActionKeywords.class.getClassLoader();
Class<?> containerClass = classLoader.loadClass(className);
Object theElm = containerClass.getDeclaredField(elementName);
WebElement theWebElm = WebElement.class.cast(theElm);  <-- Error

theElm.getType() => interface org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
theElm.getClass() => class java.lang.reflect.Field
```

How can I cast theElm to WebElement so I can just do the following as you would in the page factory?

```
theWebElm.sendKeys(textValue);
```

Comment: Why won't you pass the instance of class itself rather than just a string ( `String className`) to your `enter_text` function? You can create a parent class that all your pages will inherit from and then you can pass the class like `enterText(? extends ParentClass, ...)`

Comment: @Eugene S - Thank you for your response!  Sorry I failed to include in my original code that LoginPage is extended from a BaseClass.  But that class only has the WebDriver and test environment setup.  Can you elaborate on how it would work?  Thanks.